# Implementing a job worker pool in Go

Tags: go, queue, threadpool

Since Go does not have generics, all the premade solutions use type casting which I do not like very much. I also want to implement it on my own and tried the following code. However, sometimes it does not wait for all goroutines, am I closing the jobs channel prematurely? I do not have anything to fetch from them. I might have used a pseudo output channel too and waited to fetch the exact amount from them however I believe the following code should work too. What am I missing?

```
func jobWorker(id int, jobs <-chan string, wg sync.WaitGroup) {
    wg.Add(1)
    defer wg.Done()

    for job := range jobs {
        item := ParseItem(job)
        item.SaveItem()
        MarkJobCompleted(item.ID)
        log.Println("Saved", item.Title)
    }
}

// ProcessJobs processes the jobs from the list and deletes them
func ProcessJobs() {

    jobs := make(chan string)

    list := GetJobs()
    // Start workers
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for w := 0; w < 10; w++ {
        go jobWorker(w, jobs, wg)
    }

    for _, url := range list {
        jobs <- url
    }

    close(jobs)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call wg.Add outside of the goroutine and pass a pointer to the wait group.

If Add is called from inside the goroutine, it's possible for the main goroutine to call Wait before the goroutines get a chance to run.  If Add has not been called, then Wait will return immediately.

Pass a pointer to the goroutine. Otherwise, the goroutines use their own copy of the wait group.

```
func jobWorker(id int, jobs <-chan string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {

    defer wg.Done()

    for job := range jobs {
        item := ParseItem(job)
        item.SaveItem()
        MarkJobCompleted(item.ID)
        log.Println("Saved", item.Title)
    }
}

// ProcessJobs processes the jobs from the list and deletes them
func ProcessJobs() {

    jobs := make(chan string)

    list := GetJobs()
    // Start workers
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for w := 0; w < 10; w++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go jobWorker(w, jobs, &wg)
    }

    for _, url := range list {
        jobs <- url
    }

    close(jobs)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you are absoultely right, and seperating `wg.Add(1)` to there actually makes more sense and correct.

Comment: Actually, calling it once with `wg.Add(10)` makes even more sense ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a pointer to the waitgroup, or else every job receives it's own copy.

```
func jobWorker(id int, jobs <-chan string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    wg.Add(1)
    defer wg.Done()

    for job := range jobs {
        item := ParseItem(job)
        item.SaveItem()
        MarkJobCompleted(item.ID)
        log.Println("Saved", item.Title)
    }
}

// ProcessJobs processes the jobs from the list and deletes them
func ProcessJobs() {

    jobs := make(chan string)

    list := GetJobs()
    // Start workers
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for w := 0; w < 10; w++ {
        go jobWorker(w, jobs, &wg)
    }

    for _, url := range list {
        jobs <- url
    }

    close(jobs)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

See the difference here: [without pointer](http://play.golang.org/p/xa4UtM97qL), [with pointer](http://play.golang.org/p/vYjPuIT2VN).